# Object reference error on session

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am getting error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It errors when I try to get the value of a session. The value of the session is null but I have tried testing it to check if it is null and on the if statement it still always fails with this error.

```
string test;
if (Session["CustType"].ToString() != null || 
    Session["CustType"].ToString() != String.Empty)
{
   test = Session["CustType"].ToString();
   txtCustomerType.Text = test;
}
```

The error is on the second line of this code. I just don't know what to do because I can't do anything with it if it just errors even when I tried to check whether it is empty or not.

Comment: Session["CustType"] doesnt have any values so you cant use .ToString on it.

Comment: Take out the `ToString()` on your null check. Should it be `&&` instead of `||`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check following. Remove ToString() as calling ToString() on null gives you Object reference error.

```
Session["CustType"] != null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["CustType"]))
```

Comment: Everyone who has posted in this thread - please see this answer as the correct and most concise one.

Answer (score 0):

You should check:

```
Session["CustType"] != null
```

before using `Session["CustType"].ToString()` because if it is null, you are trying to call `ToString()` on null object.

Most concise code would be probably:

```
var test = Session["CustType"] as string;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(test))
{
    txtCustomerType.Text = test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first check null, and then call `ToString`

```
var obj = Session["CustType"];
if (obj  != null && 
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString()))
{
   txtCustomerType.Text = obj.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `ToString()` on an object, it cannot be null.  Where you have..

```
Session["CustType"].ToString() != null
```

You need to replace it with...

```
Session["CustType"] != null
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are referencing an object in a table that cannot be reached. Debug your code with breakpoints and check whether your test variable has a value assigned to it at the moment of the exception. If the count of the held table is 0, this will confirm that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have remove tostring() from session while checking null value

use this

```
if (Session["CustType"] != null && 
    Session["CustType"].ToString() != string.Empty)
```

instead

```
if (Session["CustType"].ToString() != null &&
    Session["CustType"].ToString() != String.Empty)
```